# Array index syntax in R

Tags: arrays, r

I am going over `HoltWinters` algorithm source code and having tough time understanding following syntax.

`len` value is 20, shouldn't `level[-len-1]` result `level[-21`] which will be not a valid index, isn't it? But somehow `R` treating it as `level[20]`.  I couldn't find any documentation in `R` about this syntax.

Here is part of source I am referring:

```
fitted <- ts(cbind(xhat   = final.fit$level[-len-1],
                       level  = final.fit$level[-len-1],
                       trend  = if (!is.logical(beta) || beta)
                           final.fit$trend[-len-1],
                       season = if (!is.logical(gamma) || gamma)
                           final.fit$seasonal[1L:len]),
                 start = start(lag(x, k = 1 - start.time)),
                 frequency  = frequency(x)
                 )
```

Comment: Perhaps, see `?'['`, arguments "i, j, ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscript -n for an R vector (with n > 0) means that element n is excluded.

Comment: I see. It conveys exclusion of the element. Now it make sense. Thanks!